# Getting Error "You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: apache2, lamp

I changed my Document above error when trying to access the localhost.

```
DocumentRoot /home/kunal/Development/sites
<Directory /home/kunal/Development/sites>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I ran the a2ensite for new file and restarted the apache server.
I have my sites folder permission set to 777 permission. Still I am getting this error.
Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Your directives look fine. Have you checked the user/group permissions for your document root?
Try `cat /etc/apache2/envvars` to see user/group (www-data:www-data by default). Then `chown` your document root to reflect this.

Comment: I did as you said and it shows "www-data" so I ran a command 
sudo chown www-data <<my document root>>
Still getting same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/kunal/Development/sites`
This should recursively apply permissions to all files/sub-directories under your doc root. If that still doesn't work, can you check your error log (`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`) then refresh the page again

Comment: I did so but still unable to get it to work.

The error log says
[Fri Jul 13 20:48:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Fri Jul 13 20:48:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same error, my path was similar to yours like this `/home/user/Dropbox/WebDev/ServerRoot`. I made the same mistake as you by setting permissions on the last folder or your site folder.

Set your permissions at from the 3rd folder of your file path for me I had to set permissions to the `/Dropbox` folder then it started to work I recommend you set your permissions on the `/Development` folder and it will start to work.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with sites that I have located in my `~/Dropbox` directory. I changed the permissions of the directory by running the following command and everything worked like a charm afterwards.

`$ chmod 755 ~/Dropbox`

Hope this helps.